# PicklingError when using mock to check function is called

Tags: python, pickle, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I'm having trouble testing that a method is called using `mock` -- as a simple example, let's say that the method is `os.getcwd`. I want to test that my own function, `pickle_wdir`, is calling `os.getcwd` as intended. However, the function I am testing pickles the value returned by `os.getcwd`, which results in an error.

Here's a simple example to reproduce the error.

`os_ex.py`:

```
import os
import pickle

def pickle_wdir(filename):
    dir = os.getcwd()
    with open(filename, 'wb') as handle:
        pickle.dump(dir, handle)
```

`test_os_ex.py`:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch
from os_ex import pickle_wdir


class TestPickleWdir(TestCase):
    def test_os_called(self):
        fname = 'dir.pickle'
        with patch('os_ex.os') as mocked_obj:
            pickle_wdir(fname)
            mocked_obj.getcwd.assert_called()
```

The error message returned is

`_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'unittest.mock.MagicMock'>: it's not the same object as unittest.mock.MagicMock`.

How can I test that `os.getcwd` is called without getting this `PicklingError`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to mock `os.getcwd()`, `open()` and `pickle.dump()` methods. You can use [unittest.mock.patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) as context manager to do this.

E.g.

`os_ex.py`:

```js
import os
import pickle


def pickle_wdir(filename):
    dir = os.getcwd()
    with open(filename, 'wb') as handle:
        pickle.dump(dir, handle)
```

`test_os_ex.py`:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, mock_open
from os_ex import pickle_wdir


class TestOsEx(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_pickle_wdir(self):
        fname = 'dir.pickle'
        m = mock_open(read_data='mocked data')
        with patch('os_ex.os') as mocked_obj, patch('builtins.open', m) as mocked_open, patch('pickle.dump') as mocked_dump:
            mocked_obj.getcwd.return_value = '/root'
            pickle_wdir(fname)
            mocked_obj.getcwd.assert_called()
            m.assert_called_with(fname, 'wb')
            handle = mocked_open()
            mocked_dump.assert_called_with('/root', handle)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.012s

OK
Name                                       Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/60627827/os_ex.py            6      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/60627827/test_os_ex.py      17      0   100%
------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                         23      0   100%
```